# Javascript fast button click for IE6 and IE7 for mouse-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I am programming an application by using Windows ActiveX web control which uses html buttons for input interaction. On differing versions of Windows XP this control may be IE6 or IE7. On Winodws 7 x64 with IE11 installed it is still IE7. I do not know what version is available on Windows 8.

Operating within these limitations (IE6/IE7), is there a javascript fast click solution for these browsers?

I found that handling both the `.click` and `.dblclick` events with jQuery will simulate fast click for events which trigger on "mouse up". However, I would prefer for this particular application for the event to fire on mouse-down instead of mouse-up. I can get half of it with `.onmousedown`, but `.dblclick` activates on mouse up which makes interaction jumpy on double click.

I tried various fast click implementations on the internet and was unable to find an adequate solution. I am able to use versions of jQuery prior to version 2.0.

If you feel comfortable running an executable, I've written a simple demo application which accepts a single command-line parameter for passing the target web page url. This demo will utilize your operating system's IE ActiveX control for testing purposes.

You can pass a file path as the url with this program. However, it was only tested with the IE7 ActiveX control. I don't know if a file path will work for IE6, but I believe it should.

http://codespunk.com/files/upload/html_test.zip

If someone out there is using Windows 8 and 8.1, I would be interested to know what the result is for "http://whatbrowser.org" so we can see what version of IE the control is using.

Comment: My two cents, I think `dbclick` is not recommended for use as it is not-native to web users anymore, everything on web sites is considered single click to navigate.

Comment: This may be true for modern web browsers but the IE ActiveX control is limited to IE6/7 on XP and up. If I don't handle .dbclick then this extra event gobbles up fast clicks which causes the button to appear poorly responsive.